# Google Maps overlay wont position over correct markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a list of markers to pin onto a map, each having its own overlay. It's mostly working, however the overlays are all being positioned over the top of one another instead of its corresponding marker.

Code is as follows:

```
var myCenter = getMyLocation();

function initialize()
{
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom:9,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  var locations = [
    {lat: -27.646670, lng: 152.86918630, text: 'Address #1'},
    {lat: -27.6446550, lng: 152.7822390, text: 'Address #2'},
    {lat: -27.6062480, lng: 152.7889550, text: 'Address #3'}
  ];

  // Loop through our list and plot them on the map
  locations.forEach(function (l) {

    marker =  new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(l.lat, l.lng),
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

    // Create our infoWindow panel for our marker
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: l.text
    });

    // Bind click event for our marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have a feeling that the issue is something to do with the on click `addListener` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply missing a `var`:

```
marker =  new google.maps.Marker(...
```

should be:

```
var marker =  new google.maps.Marker(
```

As a result, you only have a single global `marker` variable instead of a unique one for each marker as you should.

Since you're using `.forEach` with a callback function, that callback function provides you with a closure for each iteration of the loop. So all you need is to take advantage of that closure by making `marker` a local variable inside the callback.

Comment: Champion. I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe closure will help you? Marker is an object, because of it on every loop link to it changes. Closure will prevent it.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker){ return function () {
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
};})(marker));
```

Comment: That would work, but the extra code really isn't needed. The code *already* has a closure because of the `.forEach()` callback. All that's needed is to add the missing `var` so that `marker` becomes part of the existing closure.